# Update python dictionary from JSON file every hour

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I've been working on a Telegram bot, to serve the prices of gasoline and diesel of different petrol stations. I download a JSON file hourly with updated prices, and put them into a dictionary like this:

```
import json

with open('output1.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
f.close()

def rotul_2668():
    return (data['ListaEESSPrecio'][37]['Rótulo'])
def direccio_2668():
    return (data['ListaEESSPrecio'][37]['Dirección'])
def benzina_2668():
    return (data['ListaEESSPrecio'][37]['Precio Gasolina 95 E5'])
def dieselA_2668():
    return (data['ListaEESSPrecio'][37]['Precio Gasoleo A'])
def dieselB_2668():
    return (data['ListaEESSPrecio'][37]['Precio Gasoleo B'])
def dieselPremium_2668():
    return (data['ListaEESSPrecio'][37]['Precio Gasoleo Premium'])
def GLP_2668():
    return (data['ListaEESSPrecio'][37]['Precio Gases licuados del petróleo'])

ciutadella_2668 = {
    'rotul' : rotul_2668(),
    'direccio' : direccio_2668(),
    'benzina' : benzina_2668(),
    'dieselA' : dieselA_2668(),
    'dieselB' : dieselB_2668(),
    'dieselPremium' : dieselPremium_2668(),
    'GLP': GLP_2668()
}
```

Then call the dictionary entries from an external function. Everything runs good so far until dictionary needs to be updated and serve the new prices, which never does. Any idea why is that happening? Could be because the data stored in var "data" never gets reloaded? If that's so, what would be a possible solution?

Thank you for your time

Comment: no need for `f.close()`

Comment: which part of the code run every 1 hour and how?

Comment: Which logic should have updated the dictionary? Once you run your script and its execution is complete, it doesnt check for updates.

Comment: If you are downloading your json file from some web url, you can use `requests` library. You need to find a way to schedule updates.

Comment: True @balderman, I just assumed that closing it would force to load the updated file.

Comment: @bijay I download them via cron. About the logic that updates the dictionary, I was thinking that every time the user of the bot demands the data from that piece of code it will re-run the entire code and not just read the dictionary. You mean that I need to force the update?

Comment: The whole setup is odd. Use a database, update/add records regularly (at desired time intervals). Read the database whenever you need,

Comment: @buran It is indeed, newbie setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not reloaded because you put your code at file level. So the first time you access **ciutadella_2668** all file is imported, **output1.json** is read and dictionary is populated. Quick fix (not optimal thought) would be put it into the function

```
import json

def get_ciutadella_2668():
  with open('output1.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

  def rotul_2668():
    return (data['ListaEESSPrecio'][37]['Rótulo'])
  def direccio_2668():
    return (data['ListaEESSPrecio'][37]['Dirección'])
  def benzina_2668():
    return (data['ListaEESSPrecio'][37]['Precio Gasolina 95 E5'])
  def dieselA_2668():
    return (data['ListaEESSPrecio'][37]['Precio Gasoleo A'])
  def dieselB_2668():
    return (data['ListaEESSPrecio'][37]['Precio Gasoleo B'])
  def dieselPremium_2668():
    return (data['ListaEESSPrecio'][37]['Precio Gasoleo Premium'])
  def GLP_2668():
    return (data['ListaEESSPrecio'][37]['Precio Gases licuados del petróleo'])

  return {
    'rotul' : rotul_2668(),
    'direccio' : direccio_2668(),
    'benzina' : benzina_2668(),
    'dieselA' : dieselA_2668(),
    'dieselB' : dieselB_2668(),
    'dieselPremium' : dieselPremium_2668(),
    'GLP': GLP_2668()
  }
```

Another way could be use some [python scheduler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html) that runs every hour and update this specific variable not while reading it but when new file is fetched.

Comment: Thank you for your time @kosciej16, it worked! So, it will be running like this until I have the time to try another way, like the one suggested above about importing the JSON data into a database and take the data from there. Thank you again!